# UNIX shell script to read files, copy files and delete files

Tags: shell, unix

Hi I am writing a shell script in UNIX which reads a directory and copies the files in to another directory and then deletes the files in the first directory

I have tried this but it does not work:-

```
files"=/project/scripts/input/"

for f in $files; do
    [ mv /project/scripts/input/$f.txt /project/scripts/output/$f.xml

    rm /project/scripts/input/$f.txt ]
else

    echo "Nothing to process will try later"

    exit

fi
```

Comment: You can't use `else` and `fi` without `if`.

Comment: The `=` in an assignment goes _before_ the quote.

Comment: I'm not sure the need for a script here - Unlike `cp`, `mv` should automatically remove source files once it has copied them to the destination.

Comment: Use the `rename` command: `rename 's/\.txt/\.xml/' $files/*.txt`

Comment: @chepner No assumption required, it always removes the original. The only difference is whether it does a simple rename or a copy followed by remove.

Comment: And he's moving within the same directory, so it's obviously on the same filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is an "if" at the beginning of the routine. THe script will be called by cron and will run every 10 minutes. It will check for a *.flag file if this flag exists it will copy the .txt files from the source directory to the target directory. files"=/project/scripts/input/"
if /project/scripts/input/*.flag
for f in $files; do
    [ mv /project/scripts/input/$f.txt /project/scripts/output/$f.xml

    rm /project/scripts/input/$f.txt ]
else

    echo "Nothing to process will try later"

    exit

fi

Comment: @user2945682 - I see that you attempted to edit my answer below with your code.  Don't do that, unless there are specific points in my answer that you think need correcting.  Instead, you should edit your own question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like

```
cd $SourceDir && ( tar cfz - * | ( cd $TargetDir && tar xfz - ) )
```

(written from head/not tested...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply see my comment above.

Comment: Ah, it seems somebody deleted comments that were here. Even your 2nd comment is deleted...

Answer (score 0):

Because the structure of the script is so badly broken, it is quite hard to determine what the real intent of the script is.  So with a bit of guesswork, I'm going to give a psuedo-answer with some hints:

- `files"=/project/scripts/input/"` - I assume the intent of this line is to set the variable `files` to all the files in the `/project/scripts/input/` directory.  But this line won't do that.  Instead, because the `"=/project/scripts/input/"` part is in double quotes, it is expanded literally with no special meaning (variable assignment) given to the `=`.  So the whole line ends up being an attempt to execute `files=/project/scripts/input/`, i.e. execute the directory `input/` which is found under the relative path `files=/project/scripts/`.  A variable `$files` will not be set at all.
- As I think you already know the `else` and the `fi` must be proceeded somewhere with some kind of `if` statement.  Your question will make much more sense if you edit it to include the actual `if` statement (edit the answer itself, don't put in a comment)
- `for ...; do` statements must always be followed by a `done` statement to indicate the end of your loop
- `[` and `]` are always used specifically to test conditionals.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html.  The condition which is being tested will be within the `[` and `]` and then some conditional action will happen, depending on the outcome of the conditional.
- as mentioned in my comment, `mv` will automatically remove the source files, so there is no need for the `rm`.

In short you would do well to edit your question to provide the full script you are asking about, and what exactly you expect it to do.